# Somebody Hacked My Minecraft account and put cheats so i cant go to servers, how to get rid of them

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

As you can see by the title I've been hacked or something like that and they've put on cheats so i cant get on to Hypixel and it's annoying, if you know what to do please tell me

Answer (score 3):

There's no way anyone could've put cheats on your account. Your account doesn't hold any data aside from your authentication details, skin and cape.

What could've happened is someone hacking your account and using it as an alt on Hypixel. If so, Hypixel will have recorded that ban with someone else's IP address.

You can dispute the ban in their [Ban Appeal](https://hypixel.net/forums/ban-appeal.36/) forum section. Be sure to mention the fact that it was on a different IP, and take a screenshot of a website like [whatismyip.com](https://www.whatismyip.com/) to support your claim of it being someone else.

Also be sure to change your password on [the Mojang website](https://account.mojang.com/me/settings)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is appeal your ban on Hypixel and hope they will accept your request.